# Hide only comments

Tags: comment, hideshow

In hs-mode, is there a way to only hide the comments (C-style, delimited by `/* ...*/`), and no other blocks of code?

<sub>(there was nothing obvious in <kbd>M-x customize-group hideshow)</kbd></sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set `hs-hide-all-non-comment-function` to `#'ignore`.
If you want to do that globally put the following in your init file:

```el
  (setq hs-hide-all-non-comment-function #'ignore)
```

If you want to do that only for certain major modes replace `my-major-mode` with the major mode of your choice and put the modified line in your init file:

```el
  (add-hook 'mine-major-mode (lambda () (setq-local hs-hide-all-non-comment-function #'ignore)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer your question, but it might be an alternative to consider.

Library [**`hide-comnt.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hide-comnt.el) is designed to let you [hide or ignore comments](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideOrIgnoreComments).

- There are commands to hide, show, and toggle showing comments.
- There is a macro, `with-comments-hidden`, that you can use to wrap code that you want to ignore text in comments.
- You can set or bind option `ignore-comments-flag` to `nil` to inhibit ignoring comments by the macro.
- You can use option `hide-whitespace-before-comment-flag` to hide also the whitespace preceding a comment (other than empty lines).
- You can use option `show-invisible-comments-shows-all` to cause all invisible text to reappear when you turn off hiding comments.  (By default, only the hidden comments reappear.)

I can't speak to how well `hide-comnt.el` might play with `hs-mode`.  An untested guess is that it will work just fine.  It uses a specific value (`hide-comment`) for text property `invisible`, so I don't expect any conflict.